# Github authentication message when using commands in terminal

Tags: git, authentication

When I tried to remove a commit in terminal using my GitHub password I got this message.

How do I do this if it won't accept password?

[image]

Comment: Why not read the linked document like it asks? It lays out plenty of alternatives to password authentication.

Comment: because the linked document is generic and does't address the issue. https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+%22Support+for+password+authentication+was+removed.+Please+use+a+personal+access+token+instead.%22

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens).
When it asks for a password, you just enter your token

Comment: This does not explain what the personal token is and how to create it. It assumes people already know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a good solution after digging through all the convoluted ones on Stack including the one marked above as it does not explain where and how to create the personal token, this one does.

@dmitry , you did have the right idea but you did not provide steps needed to accomplish the solution.

This link does:

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/fix-password-authentication-github-3395e579ce74

Extra details needed:

1. Make sure you use the name the repo is under, which is not necessarily your GitHub user name.
2. You have to authorize that personal token after you create it in that developer settings area by clicking "authorize" button.
3. You then use that only that personal token as your password in terminal window when doing a push to origin.